# iPhone - Does iPhone support RTSP?

Tags: iphone, xcode, video-streaming, quicktime

I am trying to implement streaming video on iPhone with RTSP protocol.

On Mac, the QuickTime support RTSP and I tested streaming video with this.

This means iPhone can support RTSP, I think.

But I could not implement on iPhone with MPMoviePlayerController.

Who knows about this. Regard!

Comment: Refere this, [RTPS](https://github.com/dropcam/dropcam_for_iphone)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A quick search on google revealed dropcam https://github.com/dropcam/dropcam_for_iphone for iphone where an RTSP client was implemented. I would advise taking a closer look at that project.

Comment: What is that project? There are some lib projects, no executable projects and no README file. Are there any samples of using RTSP Client sample? What is dropCam?

Comment: What is deference between RTSP and RTPS?

Comment: Thank you for your advise. I saw the RTSPClient header file. Do you know how to stream/play with this library?

Comment: Link appears dead now, fwiw.